# Grep multiple lines from different files, and print them to a xml

Tags: bash

i have to create a bash script that greps multiple matches from different files. The files are all included in a directory, with the same extension (.desktop). Here's an example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=text-x-c++src
Name=button.cpp
Type=Link
URL[$e]=file://$HOME/Configs/button.cpp
X-KDE-LastOpenedWith=kate
```

The matches are URL, LastOpenedWith, Name and Icon. Every of them has to be stored into a different variable (e.g. $Name, $URL, etc...) which will be printed to a xml file, accordingly to this sintax:

```
<action label="$Name" icon="$Icon" exec="$LastOpenedWith $URL"/>
```

Creating single entries for all the .desktop files.

I have really no idea how to do this, since i'm a beginner with bash scripting, any tip will be welcomed :)

Comment: Why use grep instead of XSLT?

Comment: This question is too vague. How looks the .desktop file? What means "Every of them has to be stored into a different variable"?

Comment: You're right, sorry. I edited the post adding the original files structure. Since i'm really ignorant i probably explained myself badly. I need to print the matches as in the xml line above, for each file, a line that prints Name, Icon, etc.. Hope is clear now.

Comment: I think you can do something with sed or perl to use regular expressions to catch the text you want. For instance you can create a Perl script that would read all files in the directory and catch the text you want to add line in the XML file.

Comment: Your input and output samples show completely different data.

Comment: I'd like to, but i don't know anything about perl. I was already considering sed(which i never used), since i do not need all the line for the match, but just the part after "=", or in case of the Url, removing the part before $HOME.

Comment: @harpo: what do you mean?

Comment: @user2469372, I mean that there's no obvious mapping from the config-style sample to the XML sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
echo -e "<menu>\n<submenu>" > output.xml
for f in *.desktop; do
  Icon=$(awk -F= '/Icon/{print $2}' "$f")
  Name=$(awk -F= '/Name/{print $2}' "$f")
  URL=$(awk -F= '/URL/{print $2}' "$f")
  LastOpenedWith=$(awk -F= '/X-KDE-LastOpenedWith/{print $2}' "$f")

  echo "<action label=\"$Name\" icon=\"$Icon\" exec=\"$LastOpenedWith $URL\"/>"
done >> output.xml
echo -e "</submenu>\n</menu>" >> output.xml
```

A Perl solution using [Config::IniFiles](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Config-IniFiles-2.82/lib/Config/IniFiles.pm) could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::IniFiles;

open XML, ">/path/to/output.xml" or die $!;

print XML "<menu>\n<submenu>\n";

foreach my $file (</path/to/*.desktop>) {
  my $ini = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => "$file" );
  printf XML "<action label='%s' icon='%s' exec='%s %s'/>\n",
    $ini->val('Desktop Entry', 'Name'),
    $ini->val('Desktop Entry', 'Icon'),
    $ini->val('Desktop Entry', 'X-KDE-LastOpenedWith'),
    $ini->val('Desktop Entry', 'URL[$e]')
}

print XML "</submenu>\n</menu>\n";

close XML;
```

Comment: This spawns four processes per input file--so shouldn't be used on busy systems, slow uncached filesystems, etc.

Comment: @JohnZwinck True. But from the question (multiple `*.desktop` files in a single directory) that doesn't seem to be the case here. Anyway, added a Perl solution to avoid the issue.

Comment: Question: i have to add the lines <menu> and <submenu> at the beginning of the file, and their closing tags </menu> and </submenu> at the end of it. How to do it, avoiding them to be repeated every line before the <action> ones generated by the script? (and in case, how to do that on perl?)

Comment: Thanks again. This is exactly what i was looking for! 'd like to ask you some things about the perl script, but don't want to be annoying.

Comment: @user2469372 This place is for answering questions. If you need something explained: ask away.

Comment: Ok then. Let's say i want to create another perl script, this time it has to do the same job, but including files in subdirectories too. The folder is /usr/share/applications/, and i want to extract the lines: Name, Icon, Exec, and Type (for this, i'd like also to create different tags in the xml file, but it's not meant be printed itself. I'll explain later). Here's an example of the original desktop file: http://pastebin.com/r9gKUGhL, and the awful attempt to edit your script to do what i explained: http://pastebin.com/NKT0pnCf . By running it in a terminal i get an error at line 13.

Comment: Worked just fine for me when I copy/pasted both the desktop file and your modified script.

Comment: I see. Strange. Here it says: "Missing argument in printf at ./Apps.perl line 13."

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in one awk script:

parse.awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS="="
}

/^Name/ {
    name=$2
}

/^Icon/ {
    icon=$2
}

/^URL/ {
    url=$2
}

/LastOpenedWith/ {
    lastopenedwith=$2
    printf("<action label=\"%s\" icon=\"%s\" exec=\"%s %s\"/>\n", name, icon, lastopenedwith, url)
}
```

by calling

```
./parse.awk *.desktop
```

this script work assuming X-KDE-LastOpenedWith occurs on the last line of every *.desktop file...

Comment: On the one hand this is sort of cool, and kudos for doing it with a single awk instead of many.  On the other hand, I hope this doesn't make its way into a production system (too brittle).

Comment: Nice! But unfortunately i can't use it, The script has to be called by a program, which assumes it has to deal with a .sh file :(

Comment: you can put `./parse.awk` in a .sh script if you want... or call awk with the whole script in parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you're new to Bash, here's a solution: use Python.  It's a much better programming language, and it comes with a library designed to parse config files just like the ones you're dealing with: http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html .  It can easily write XML too, and unlike Bash, you won't have to learn a second language like `sed` to get the job done--you can do everything with Python.

Edit: here you go, a Python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ConfigParser
import sys

for filename in sys.argv[1:]: # each argument except the program name itself
  parser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
  parser.read(filename)
  name = parser.get('Desktop Entry', 'Name')
  icon = parser.get('Desktop Entry', 'Icon')
  app = parser.get('Desktop Entry', 'X-KDE-LastOpenedWith')
  url = parser.get('Desktop Entry', 'URL[$e]')

  print '<action label="{}" icon="{}" exec="{} {}"/>'.format(name, icon, app, url)
```

And since you said the calling program expects a shell script, I included the "shebang line" at the top so it shouldn't know the difference (your shell will invoke Python automatically).

Comment: It's not an answer. It's rather a comment. If you advertise Python, you should write an example how to resolve the question in this language.

Comment: Hey, I gave a pointer to the library that directly parses inputs like the OP showed.  There is no rule of StackOverflow that says "answers must include complete code."

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the link.

Comment: Interesting. I know a few about python (but soon i'll start to study it seriously). Tried from terminal, but it gave me an error at the last line ( it seems something with the dot).

Answer (score 0):

```
#This functions gets a field from a ".desktop" file
get_variable()
{
    FILE=$1
    FIELD=$2

    #grep the lines that starts with the fields and cuts them after '=' char
    grep -m 1 -e "^$FIELD" "$FILE" | cut -f 2 -d"="
}

#gets all the .desktop files in the current folder
#gets the specified fields from them
for file in *.desktop; do
   name=get_variable "$file" "Name"
   type=get_variable "$file" "Type"
   icon=get_variable "$file" "Icon"
   url=get_variable "$file" "URL"
   last=get_variable "$file" "X-KDE-LastOpenedWith"
   #echo the XML file
   echo "<action label=\"$name\" icon=\"$icon\" exec=\"$last $url\"/> "
done
```